# how do i find out if a certain button has been clicked like in check boxes

Tags: jquery

e.g

```
if()//  button1 is clicked
{
  alert("Button 1 was clicked");
}
if()//   button2 is clicked
{
  alert("Button 2 was clicked");
}
```

Comment: By 'clicked', I assume you mean 'checked'

Answer (score 3):

```
//you can change type to submit if its a form submit button
$("input[type='button']").click(function(){
     alert("button with the id: "+$(this).attr("id")+" was clicked!");
});
```

You can use the button id as an identifier.

Comment: @ameosrivera: he wants diff alerts for diff button.

Comment: i see, but there needs to be a different thing on each button to have different alerts, here i use the id.

Answer (score 3):

```
jQuery('#button1, #button2').click(function () {
    if (this.id == 'button1') {
        alert('Button 1 was clicked');
    }
    else if (this.id == 'button2') {
        alert('Button 2 was clicked');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming in my answer that you are looking for whether a checkbox has been checked, and not clicked. That would seem the most logical inference from your question. Let me know if this is incorrect.

Use the [.is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/) function

```
if ($("#Button1").is(":checked")){
    alert("Button 1 was clicked");
}

if ($("#Button2").is(":checked")){
    alert("Button 2 was clicked");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#button1').click(function() {
  alert('Button 1 Clicked');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(":button").click(function(){

var $id=$(this).attr("id");
alert("Button"+ id);
});
```

it will work for each button type input element